# git checkout -f in python

Tags: python, git, vcs-checkout

I want to make a checkout on a version of a Git repository in Python.
I am using the following code lines:

```
from git import Git
g = Git(os.getcwd())
g.checkout(row[2])
```

the question is how can I make a forced checkout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation, the checkout method takes keyword arguments:

```
g.checkout(row[2], force=True)
```

Should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

According to [reference](http://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#git.refs.head.Head.checkout) `checkout` function takes first optional argument force=False `checkout(force=False, **kwargs)`

Therefore, you can just simply call it with first argument force=True, to force the force checkout, like this

`g.checkout(force=True, row[2])`

Comment: Parameters should be reversed  g.checkout( row[2], force=True)